# Trying to Make a Guild Config - Discord.PY

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Ok so I'm trying to build a global config for my bot. I have a `guilds.json` file already implemented which stores the channel ids and guild ids of each guild it is in. What I want to do is make a config command that allows each guild to specify which command are allowed in their guild and uses the `guilds.json` file to specify which channels to allow them in.

I'm using discord.py rewrite if it helps.

Far for the command I have this:

````py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import os
import sys
import discord.utils

class Config(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    with open("./data/guilds.json") as f:
        json.load(f)

     # Here is a base for my config command.
    @commands.command(name="Config", aliases=["config", "setup", "Setup", "settings", "Settings"])
    @commands.guild_only()
    async def _config(self, ctx, guild):
        red = discord.Color.dark_red()
        cli = self.client.user
        response1 = ("...")
        css1 = str(f"""```css\n{response1}```""")
        for channel in guild.channels:
            if str(channel.id) not in "./data/guilds.json":
            return
        embed = discord.Embed(color=red)
        embed.set_author(name=cli.display_name, icon_url=cli.avatar_url)
        embed.add_field(name="First Time Config", value=css1, inline=False)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=cli.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=guild.name, icon_url=guild.icon_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        # some sort of code to create a guild json fil to store the config in here




def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Config(client))
````

My issue is that I don't know how to build the setup command itself.

I would like for it to create a separate `{guild_id}.json` file for each guild in order to store the guild's config in.

The command needs to be interactive and needs to be for setting up the specific channels for commands, announcements, autoresponses, support systems, etc.

--EDIT--

Here is my main `bot.py` file. This is what I use to load my cogs. I'm working on a change to the prefix command as well so just ignore that part for now...

````py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import json


with open("./data/config.json") as f:
    prefixes = json.load(f)
    default_prefix = "r?"


def prefix(client, message):
    id = message.guild.id
    return prefixes.get(id, default_prefix)


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)
client.remove_command('help')

for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    guilds = client.guilds
    data = {}
    cli = client.user
    gold = discord.Color.dark_gold()
    for guild in guilds:
        data[guild.id] = []
        for channel in guild.channels:
            data[guild.id].append(channel.id)
    with open("./data/guilds.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
        print(f"A guild file has been created for {guild.name}:{guild.id}.")

@client.command(name="Prefix", aliases=["prefix", "setprefix"], hidden=True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
async def _prefix(ctx, new_prefix):
    guild = ctx.guild
    msg = ctx.message
    prefixes[msg.guild.id] = new_prefix
    cli = client.user
    gold = discord.Color.dark_gold()
    with open("./data/config.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
        await msg.add_reaction(emoji="✅")


@_prefix.error
async def _prefix_error(ctx, error):
    guild = ctx.guild
    msg = ctx.message
    cli = client.user
    red = discord.Color.dark_red()
    e_1 = str("""```css\nPlease pass in all required arguments.```""")
    e_2 = str("""```css\nYou do not have permission to use this command.```""")
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        embed = discord.Embed(color=red, name=cli.display_name, timestamp=msg.created_at)
        embed.set_author(name="Command Failed", icon_url=cli.avatar_url)
        embed.add_field(name="Missing Required arguments", value=e_1, inline=False)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=cli.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
        await msg.send(embed=embed)
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        embed = discord.Embed(color=red, name=cli.display_name, timestamp=msg.created_at)
        embed.set_author(name="Access denied", icon_url=cli.avatar_url)
        embed.add_field(name="Insufficient Permissions", value=e_2, inline=False)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=cli.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
        await msg.send(embed=embed)


client.run(str(os.environ.get('BOT_TOKEN')))
````

and this is my `Events.py` file that has the code for the `guilds.json` file in it:

````py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Activity, ActivityType
from discord.utils import find
import os
import json
import random

class Events(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener(name="on_ready")
    async def _on_ready_1(self):
        cli = self.client.user
        data = {}
        for guild in self.client.guilds:
            data[guild.id] = []
        for channel in guild.channels:
                data[guild.id].append(channel.id)
        with open("./data/guilds.json", "w") as file:
            json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
        await self.client.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name=f"r?help | in {len(self.client.guilds)} servers", url="https://www.twitch.tv/discord"))
        print(" ")
        print("License")
        print(" ")
        print("Copyright (c) Joshua Lewis")
        print(" ")
        print("Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy")
        print("of this software and associated documentation files (the Software), to deal")
        print("in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights")
        print("to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell")
        print("copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is")
        print("furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:")
        print(" ")
        print("The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all")
        print("copies or substantial portions of the Software.")
        print(" ")
        print("THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED AS IS, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR")
        print("IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,")
        print("FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE")
        print("AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER")
        print("LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,")
        print("OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE")
        print("SOFTWARE.")
        print("Connecting to Discord API")
        print("...")
        print("......")
        print(".........")
        print(f"Logged in as : {cli.name}#{cli.discriminator}")
        print("Collecting list of connected guilds")
        print("...")
        print("......")
        print(".........")
        print("Connected Guilds:")
        print(f"{self.client.guilds}")
        print(f"A guild file has been created for {guild.name}:{guild.id}.")


    @commands.Cog.listener(name="on_guild_join")
    async def _on_guild_join_1(self, guild):           
        await guild.create_text_channel("announcements-and-suggestions")
        await guild.create_text_channel("log")
        cli = self.client.user
        gold = discord.Color.dark_gold()
        for channel in guild.channels:
            if str(channel.name) == "announcements-and-suggestions":
                response1 = str(f"""```css\nHello {guild.name}! I am {self.client.user.display_name}. Thank you for inviting me. I hope we have a lot of fun.```""")
                response2 = str("""```css\nTo see what commands I have available type r?help.```""")
                response3 = str("""```css\nIf you want to see how to use my AutoResponder type gethelp.```""")
                embed = discord.Embed(color=gold)
                embed.set_author(name=cli.display_name, icon_url=cli.avatar_url)
                embed.add_field(name="Yo! I'm in!", value=response1, inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name="Check out my Commands", value=response2, inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name="I even have an Auto Responder", value=response3, inline=False)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=cli.avatar_url)
                embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
                await channel.send(embed=embed)
                print(f'{cli.display_name} has entered {guild.name}:{guild.id}')

    @commands.Cog.listener(name="on_message_delete")
    async def _on_message_delete_1(self, message):
        ctx = self.client.get_context
        guild = message.author.guild
        author = message.author
        ch = message.channel
        cli = self.client.user
        content = message.content
        orange = discord.Color.dark_orange()
        for channel in guild.channels:
            if str(channel.name) == "log":
                msg_del = str(f"""```css\n{content}```""")
                aut_name = str(f"""```css\n{author.display_name}```""")
                ch_name = str(f"""```css\n{ch.name}```""")
                embed = discord.Embed(color=orange, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
                embed.set_author(name="Message Deleted", icon_url=cli.avatar_url)
                embed.add_field(name=f"Message", value=msg_del, inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name=f"Message Author", value=aut_name, inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name=f"Channel", value=ch_name, inline=False)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=author.avatar_url)
                embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
                message.embed = (content)
                await channel.send(embed=embed)
                print(f'message: {content} by {author.display_name} was deleted in {ch.name}')



    @commands.Cog.listener(name="on_member_join")
    async def _on_member_join_1(self, ctx, member):
        guild = ctx.guild
        cli = self.client.user
        gold = discord.Color.dark_gold()
        user_join = str(f"""```css\n{member} has entered {guild.name}```""")
        for channel in guild.channels:
            if str(channel.name) == "log":                
                embed = discord.Embed(color=gold)
                embed.set_author(name=cli.display_name, icon_url=cli.avatar_url)
                embed.add_field(name="Use Joined", value=user_join, inline=False)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=cli.avatar_url)
                embed.set_image(url=member.avatar_url)
                embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
                await channel.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.Cog.listener(name="on_member_remove")
    async def _on_member_remove_1(self, ctx, member):
        guild = ctx.guild
        cli = self.client.user
        red = discord.Color.dark_red()
        for channel in guild.channels:
            if str(channel.name) == "log":                
                user_left = str(f"""```css\n{member} has left {guild.name}```""")
                embed = discord.Embed(color=red)
                embed.set_author(name=cli.display_name, icon_url=cli.avatar_url)
                embed.add_field(name="User Left", value=user_left, inline=False)
                embed.set_image(url=member.avatar_url)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=cli.avatar_url)
                embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
                await channel.send(embed=embed)




def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Events(client))
````

This is how my `guilds.json` is formatted. I omitted the actual IDs.

```js
{
    "GUILD ID": [
        CHANNEL_ID1,
        CHANNEL_ID2,
        CHANNEL_ID3        
    ]
}
```

Here is a basic idea of how I'm thinking on formatting the `{guild.id}.json` file if it works:

```js
{
  "Guild Prefix":  "CUSTOM PREFIX",
  "Announce Channel": "CHANNEL ID",
  "Logs Channel": "CHANNEL ID",
  "Levels Channel": "CHANNEL ID"
}
```

Comment: I am implementing a similar system to this and the best way to do it is with the commands extension and the @check decorators. Beyond that, the scope of this question is too broad as it stands, this site is more for solving specific problems you are having with your code

Comment: How would I go about using the check decorators to do this then?  I've been searching for a way to do this and there isn't a single mention anywhere on how to do it. And the official docs don't make any sense to me. 

I understand it better with a proper display of how it's done rather than explaining what each thing means.

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#checks it is right here. I don't know if you are using commands or not but its really useful

Comment: I managed to make the `guilds.josn` file with the answer from this question that I posted before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62605586/how-to-store-server-and-user-ids-in-json-file-with-discord-py?rq=1

Comment: again that's not what I'm looking for. I'm trying to build a guild setup command to let people specify what channels to use things in. Not trying to limit to channels that re only in one guild.

I edited what little i have for the setup command into my main post. I need to build a guil setup command so i can make the commands run off of that but tuntil I have that guild setup command the checks are useless.

Comment: That is literally what I used: https://github.com/RyanSchaefer/OneBot/blob/master/src/AdminCommands.py, I created a separate (connection neutered) bot for each guild then each bot has its own list of commands and the protections for each of those commands. Right now it focuses on `Cogs` but it is applicable to commands (it would be trivial to append a predicate to the `Commands.check` list to check which user/role is calling the command before calling it).

Comment: Unfortunately since I'm running off the free Heroku plan I don't want to make a separate bot for each guild. that completely defeats the purpose of making a `Config.py` cog.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216994/discussion-between-ryan-schaefer-and-nimbi).

Comment: I Updated the main post with info on how I want to store the information into the `(guild.id}.json` file. Sorry for my slow response to that. It's almost midnight here so I'm not fully there in the head rn.

Answer (score 0):

**for reading the values and deserialization**

> ```
> use with open("filename", "r") as _data:
>     data = _data
>     user = data[user]
> ```

**for writing values and serialization**

> ```
> #serialization
> data = {'people':[{'name': 'Scott', 'name2': 'billy', 'name3': 'jack'}]}
> dumped = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
>
> #writing into json file
> use with open("filename", "w") as _data:
>     _data.write(dumped)
> ```

**if a json file with `filename` doesn't exist it will create a JSON file with that name in the project folder.**

so you can do like...

```
#define guild
guild = ....

#then
use with open(f"{guild}.json", "w") as data:
    data.write(....)
    ...
```

hope it works:)